# How do I move specific values in a column up one row based on values in other columns?

Tags: r

The following code creates a dataframe very similar to the one I'm working with.

```
condition <- c("ITI", "pos","ITI", "ITI", "neg", "ITI", "ITI", "ITI", "pos", "ITI", "neg", "ITI", "ITI", "pos", "ITI")

response <- c("None", 6, "None", "None", "None", 7, "None", "None", 7, "None", "None", 6, "None", 6, "None")

rt <- c(NA, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, .2, NA, NA, 1.2, NA, NA, .4, NA, 1.4, NA)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(condition, response, rt))
```

The conditions are listed in the condition column, responses in response and reaction times in rt. The issue that I'm having is that "ITI" trials should not have anything in the response or rt columns and if they do then it means that the subject answered late. I need to identify the places where this happened and move the values up one row. I also need to add 2 to the rt value as I do this.

I was able to figure out how to identify the values using logical indexing but I can't figure out how to move them to the appropriate place.

```
d$response[d$condition == "ITI" & d$response != "None"] 

d$rt[d$condition == "ITI" & !is.na(d$rt)]
```

This is what the dataframe should look like.

```
condition <- c("ITI", "pos","ITI", "ITI", "neg", "ITI", "ITI", "ITI", "pos", "ITI", "neg", "ITI", "ITI", "pos", "ITI")

response <- c("None", 6, "None", "None", 7, "None", "None", "None", 7, "None", 6, "None", "None", 6, "None")

rt <- c(NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 2.2, NA, NA, NA, 1.2, NA, 2.4, NA, NA, 1.4, NA)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(condition, response, rt))
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  mutate(
    rt = as.numeric(as.character(rt))
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(response, rt),
    ~ case_when(
      lead(condition) == 'ITI' & !is.na(lead(rt)) ~ if (class(.) == 'factor') lead(.) else lead(.) + 2,
      condition == 'ITI' & !is.na(rt) ~ lag(.),
      TRUE ~ .
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
   condition response  rt
1        ITI     None  NA
2        pos        6 1.5
3        ITI     None  NA
4        ITI     None  NA
5        neg        7 2.2
6        ITI     None  NA
7        ITI     None  NA
8        ITI     None  NA
9        pos        7 1.2
10       ITI     None  NA
11       neg        6 2.4
12       ITI     None  NA
13       ITI     None  NA
14       pos        6 1.4
15       ITI     None  NA
```

Comment: Thanks @IceCreamToucan - have overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d$rt <- as.numeric(as.character(d$rt))
row_index <- which(d$condition == 'ITI' & d$response != 'None' & !is.na(d$rt))
new_d <- d
new_d [row_index-1, 'response'] <- d[row_index, 'response']
new_d [row_index-1, 'rt'] <- as.numeric(as.character(d[row_index, 'rt']))+2
new_d [row_index, 'response'] <- 'None'
new_d [row_index, 'rt'] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Soodi's answer, but the syntax is a little nicer (imo) due to data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, rt := as.numeric(as.character(rt))]

i <- dt[, which(condition == 'ITI' & !is.na(rt))]
d[i - 1, c('response', 'rt') := d[i, .(response, rt + 2)]]
d[i, c('response', 'rt') := .('None', NA)]

d
#     condition response  rt
#  1:       ITI     None  NA
#  2:       pos        6 1.5
#  3:       ITI     None  NA
#  4:       ITI     None  NA
#  5:       neg        7 2.2
#  6:       ITI     None  NA
#  7:       ITI     None  NA
#  8:       ITI     None  NA
#  9:       pos        7 1.2
# 10:       ITI     None  NA
# 11:       neg        6 2.4
# 12:       ITI     None  NA
# 13:       ITI     None  NA
# 14:       pos        6 1.4
# 15:       ITI     None  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting task! Here is how I would approach it.

First, let us for a moment not worry about `ITI` and `None`.

```
cond.f <- condition[ condition != "ITI" ]
resp.f <- response[ response != "None" ]
rt.f <- rt[ !is.na(rt) ]

all(c(length(cond.f), length(resp.f)) == length(rt.f)) # TRUE

d.f <- data.frame(condition=cond.f, response=resp.f, rt=rt.f)
```

Now we need to fill out the `ITI`'s.

```
## indices of the ITI rows:
ITI <- d$condition == "ITI"

## nmap 
nmap <- rep(NA, nrow(d))
nmap[ !ITI ] <- 1:sum(!ITI)
```

OK, so this was a bit convoluted, but basically `nmap` holds now at the right positions in the original `d` the indices from `d.f`. And on all other positions it is NA, so we can now do

```
d.f <- d.f[ nmap, ]
```

and d.f now has the same number of rows as d, except that rows that correspond to ITI are now full of NA's. Let us get rid of the NA's:

```
d.f[ ITI, ] <- data.frame("ITI", "None", NA)
rownames(d.f) <- NULL
```

Result:

```
> d.f
   condition response  rt
1        ITI     None  NA
2        pos        6 1.5
3        ITI     None  NA
4        ITI     None  NA
5        neg        7 0.2
6        ITI     None  NA
7        ITI     None  NA
8        ITI     None  NA
9        pos        7 1.2
10       ITI     None  NA
11       neg        6 0.4
12       ITI     None  NA
13       ITI     None  NA
14       pos        6 1.4
15       ITI     None  NA
```